# @angular/router: Routes data not retrieved

Tags: angular

I have the following Angular records component:

[image: Component tree view]

**Note:** this Angular project has been generated with JHipster. To build my record component I was inspired by the record entity code that has been generated. By the way, I use the record service that already exists in this folder to get a Record entity from backend.

[image: JHipster record component]

In my html I want to display some attributes of a Record object in a table.

I would like this table to have several pages. The part of the code I implemented in my `records.component.ts` that doesn't work fine is the following:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.handleNavigation();
    this.registerChangeInRecords();
}

protected handleNavigation(): void {
    combineLatest(this.activatedRoute.data, this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap, (data: Data, params: ParamMap) => {
      const page = params.get('page');
      const pageNumber = page !== null ? +page : 1;
      const sort = (params.get('sort') ?? data['defaultSort']).split(','); //error here
      const predicate = sort[0];
      const ascending = sort[1] === 'asc';
      if (pageNumber !== this.page || predicate !== this.predicate || ascending !== this.ascending) {
        this.predicate = predicate;
        this.ascending = ascending;
        this.loadPage(pageNumber, true);
      }
    }).subscribe();
  }
```

`activatedRoute` is a `ActivatedRoute` object from `@angular/router` library.

When I first load the page, there is no param in the URL, so the default parameters should be taken into account. The problem is that `this.activatedRoute.data` is empty:

[image: data empty]

Then, I have the following error:

[image]

This data object should contain the following attributes (like the record entity page):

[image: data expected]

These attributes are set in the `records.route.ts`:

[image: records.route.ts]

And this constant is declared in my `records.module.ts`:

[image: records.module.ts]

I don't understand what I'm missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you paste your complete(imports and constructor) component? Or make a codesandbox, it appears to be a problem on not initializing the ActivatedRoute in component but I can't say it certainly before looking at component

Comment: Your code needed refactoring. Should I explain you as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through your source and found some structural problems correcting that I was able to resolve the error.

1. You were not using Resolver in route. The key message will resolve your observable.

   ```
   {
    path: '',
    resolve:{message : RecordsResolve},
    component: RecordsComponent,
    data: {
    authorities: [Authority.USER],
    defaultSort: 'id,asc',
    pageTitle: 'records.title',
   }
   ```
2. You were using different Routes in records-routing.module.ts.

   Before

   ```
   @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
   })
   export class RecordsRoutingModule {}
   ```

After

```
  @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(recordsRoute)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
 })
 export class RecordsRoutingModule {}
```

3. If you use separate routing file then there is no need to define child routes in module file. RecordsModule before

   ```
   @NgModule({
   declarations: [RecordsComponent],
   imports: [DigicliSharedModule, RecordsRoutingModule, 
    RouterModule.forChild(recordsRoute)],
   })
   ```

After

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [RecordsComponent],
 imports: [DigicliSharedModule, RecordsRoutingModule],
})
```

Finally you can cleanup the code by removing unused imports.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I made the changes but I still have the error, I don't understand

Comment: I have requested access on your repo, you might have to approve it @mailmeonarpit

Comment: Ok I saw what I was missing, thank you for your help!  So if I sum up my mistake: I've put the code in the wrong file. I've put it in the module file (records.module.ts) whereas I had a separate routing file (records-routing.module.ts) .